# Using JQuery to check if Mootools ajax content has loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, mootools

I have a page that is running both JQuery and Mootools. The mootools library is loading a dynamic menu using AJAX and it comes in after the Dom has loaded

I want to use JQuery to add a class to that menu, after it has loaded. Is there any way with JQuery to check that the Mootools AJAX menu has loaded?! document.ready won't cut it I guess.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just a note, using two libraries actively on a page (especially if both modify DOM or add EvenListeners) should be avoided, because this could result in a failure of their corresponding cleanup scripts an that could cause memory leaks. This would be problematic especially for pages that change their content by Ajax.

Comment: Thanks t.niese, you are absolutely right and it's not ideal. I'm trying to work with an old CMS and this is my only option basically. Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to solve everyone's problems, but it worked for me. I named the JQuery function, then found the HTML include that was being added using Mootools AJAX and called the function at the bottom of the include. It's not pretty, but it works :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know mootools well, does the ajax menu have a callback when it is finished with loading? If yes then you could _[with the note in my other comment in mind]_ there trigger a custom jquery event on e.g. the menu container something like `$(menucontainer).trigger("ajaxMenuLoaded");`. This would have the advantage that if you replace the mootools menu with a jquery implementation, the only thing you need to care about is that you there also trigger that event, but you don't need to know who is listening to it. (_soft binding_ with events vs _hard binding_ with direct function call)

Comment: Thanks t.niese. Been looking around for some Mootools documentation about it, but can't find much. Your idea makes a lot of sense though, thanks for your help.